# PHP: URL with a quote results in backslash in GET-parameter?

Tags: php, apache, url, url-encoding, stripslashes

If I enter the URL `http://localhost/script.php?a="` into the URL bar of Chrome, where script.php is the following test code:

```
var_dump( $_GET );
print '<br>';
var_dump( urldecode($_GET['a']) );
die();
```

The result looks like

```
array(1) { ["a"]=> string(2) "\"" } 
string(2) "\""
```

It seems that Chrome (or Apache/PHP?) is adding a backslash before the quote. The same thing happens if I use %22 instead of the quote character in the URL. It shouldn't be this way, should it?

I can't recall ever having this issue before, but this is a rather "new" (to me) install of PHP and Apache, so could it be some configuration on my installation that's causing this?

Comment: Sounds like you have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) and should upgrade to a new version of PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below  -

```
var_dump( $_GET );
print '<br>';
var_dump( urldecode(stripslashes($_GET['a'])));
die();
```

This is because magic_quotes is ON in your php.ini file - 
You can add below in php.ini , this should work.

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

Comment: Well of course stripslashes() will work, but should it really be necessary on a GET-parameter?? I can't recall ever having to do that before?

Comment: Doh! That was it, just found it myself too. If you update your original answer I'll accept it...